# CodeIgniter - Model cannot access global variables in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to access global variables from a model. The global variable is set from a controller:

```
function sets(){
        $value = $this->input->post('current_id');
        $anywhere = array('current_id'=>$value);
        $this->load->vars($anywhere);

}
```

But the model doesn't know the value of the current id:

```
$session_id = $this->load->get_var('current_id');
```

Comment: Couldn't you set up the call to the model to expect this id as a parameter if you need it?

Comment: [Globals? In your models? This sounds like a terrible idea.](http://tomnomnom.com/posts/why-global-state-is-the-devil-and-how-to-avoid-using-it)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Pass a variable to the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the CodeIgniter Model doesn't have access to the values that you're looking for.  But there is hope! There are a few ways to go about having getting access to the parameters that are loaded from the request, choose your poison, but having a *defined contract interface* for your model is, in my opinion, something that makes writing code easier and less of a hassle to maintain down the line.

**A reference to the CodeIgniter object can be grabbed like so:**

```
$ci =& get_instance();
$session_id = $ci->load->get_var('current_id');
```

Of course this would be the nasty way to go about getting at your data. A better approach would be to pass it in to the model itself as a parameter. You're not going to be paying for much in doing so, and it gives you a contract signature on the method where you can point and say "Hey, this *should* be the *current_id* of the model:

```
function sets($session_id)
{
...
}
```

And, of course, you would just pass in the value you wish *$current_id* to be as an argument in that function call. This gives you the flexibility of not having to rely on the fact that you're populating the model from a POST HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

The CI_Model class doesn't have a Loader, so $this->load doesn't exist in a model.

$this->load->get_var() is for controllers to use. From the [Loader documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html) -

> This is useful if for any reason a var is set in a library or another controller method using $this->load->vars().

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$ci =& get_instance();
$ci->load->get_var('current_id');
```

But my think, this isn't good idea.

You can use input->post() method on model or set variable with model function arguments.